# 3d analogue of an ellipse

Tags: geometry

An ellipse is the set of all points X in 2d space such that the the sum of the distances AX and BX is a given constant constant, where A and B are given points. What is the name for the set of all points X in 3d space such that the sum of the distances AX and BX is a given constant, where A and B are given points?

Comment: Are you talking about an [Ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid)?

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate your elipse defined by $A$, $B$ and that distance around the axis $AB$, you obtain a prolate [spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid), which is a special kind of [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid).