# Terminology for the 3D Analogue of an Ellipse Defined by the Sum of Distances to Two Fixed Points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, ellipsoids

Consider the definition of an ellipse in a two-dimensional space, where an ellipse is defined as the set $S_2$ of all points $\mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for which the sum of the Euclidean distances to two fixed points $\mathbf{F_1}, \mathbf{F_2} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a constant $c$, mathematically expressed as:
$$
S_2 = \big\{ \mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; \vert \; \|\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{F_1}\|_2 + \|\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{F_2}\|_2 = c \big\}.
$$

I am interested in extending this concept into a three-dimensional space. Suppose we have a set $S_3$ of all points $\mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which the sum of the Euclidean distances to two fixed points $\mathbf{F_1}, \mathbf{F_2} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ remains constant $c$, mathematically represented as:
$$
S_3 = \big\{ \mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \; \vert \; \|\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{F_1}\|_2 + \|\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{F_2}\|_2 = c \big\}.
$$

What is the appropriate mathematical term to describe the shape or set $S_3$ in a three-dimensional context, analogous to how the term "ellipse" is used in two dimensions? Also, are there any specific properties or characteristics associated with this three-dimensional shape that distinguish it from its two-dimensional counterpart?

I am asking this question because some say it is an *ellipsoid* ([3d analogue of an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764383/3d-analogue-of-an-ellipse)), while some say it is **not** an ellipsoid ([Given in 3D Ellipsoid semi major axis, how can we find the distance between two focal points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221025/given-in-3d-ellipsoid-semi-major-axis-how-can-we-find-the-distance-between-two)).

> An ellipsoid doesn't have foci.

Comment: It's definitely an ellipsoid, as it's a bounded [quadric surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric). In general, ellipsoids don't have foci, but yours is a *specific kind* of ellipsoid, obtained by rotating a planar ellipse about its major axis; the foci of that planar ellipse serve as foci for the full surface. Another, more specialized, term for it is [prolate spheroid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateSpheroid.html). (FYI, an [oblate spheroid](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroid) results from rotating a planar ellipse about its *minor* axis.)

Comment: See my older post concerning **focal conics** [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/definition-of-an-ellipsoid-based-on-its-focal-points/1837886#1837886).